# We have configured Azure CICD pipeline, for that i need to generate a text file that contain all pull request details

Tags: templates, azure-pipelines, devops

this was the custom script we have written to generate the table with column names as Pr number, Raised, Approved, time and date, files modified (taken from the latest commit on that pr).
I am getting all the values in the table but unable to get the files modified ,can any one help

```
  PR Number
  Raised
  Approved
  Commit Folders
  Date and Time Completed



{{#each pullRequests}}

  {{this.pullRequestId}}
  {{this.createdBy.displayName}}
  
    {{#if this.reviewers.length}}
      {{#each this.reviewers}}
        {{this.displayName}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}
      {{/each}}
    {{else}}
      N/A
    {{/if}}
  
  
    {{#each commits}}
      {{#if (eq ../this.pullRequestId this.pullRequestId)}}
        {{#each this.changes}}
          - Path: {{this.item.path}}<br>
        {{/each}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  
  {{moment this.completedTime "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"}}

{{/each}}
```

Need to get the files modified from the latest commit on the pr`your text`